# Get Email Preview Thumbnail

Tags: email, marketing-cloud

From the Platform, i can easily access the Thumbnail, however from within the SOAP API, this is very difficult to do. I've tried some suggested comments I've found with User Token, passing it both in POST and GET request; Failed, even tried submitting a LOGIN post via the LoginURL returned with it, and then quickly trying to access it.. also failed, thought maybe some cookies might exist in the Login Response and I could place them into the thumbnail, but they're all cleared for that particular response.. This is silly, can someone please find a way to make this work? I am about to write some logic that will just simply Login to the platform in code much like I would in person, to obtain the thumbnails that way, I was trying to avoid it because its stupid.. but it seems you guys are leaving me little choice.

The URL found within Exact Target portal, is as follows:

```
https://members.s6.exacttarget.com/Content/Email/EmailThumbnail.aspx?eid=[EMAIL_ID]&w=[WIDTH]&h=[HEIGHT]&showHF=true
```

I am trying to find a way to get this same image from SOAP API, so I can cache and store it locally within our "Artwork Manager";

our software is fully automated against ET, and ideally people will be able to create/edit the emails from our application as well.. currently we're able to retrieve the ID's and Names of existing Emails, and use those to send new Emails.. it is simply a bother to be completely missing the ability to "Preview" the email ID you're about to select when setting up a marketing campaign.

Comment: Can you share the URL that you expect to pull the thumbnail from? Worst case it should be possible to screen scrape it out.

Comment: Also, if this is an ExactTarget question, please tag it as such. Otherwise people will get confused and think you are asking about core Salesforce.

Comment: There is a new route going to QA in our 2014-03 release. Doesn't help you immediately, but we are moving the right direction here.

Comment: Hello Kelly, can you confirm if this new route made it in a recent release? I can't see such functionality in the current release. We need to retrieve image thumbnails of emails from the API too.

Comment: I know you can retrieve the thumbnail from the URL if you are logged into ET. I am wondering if you can use SSO via SAML to do the authentication and then the URLs will work in the browser session? Haven't tried this yet but might be an option: http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/admin/single_sign_on_authentication_via_saml_20/

Comment: Was this feature ever released?

Answer (score 3):

Many moons later, this can be done with the REST API, using the following endpoint:

```
GET /asset/v1/assets/{id}/thumbnail
```

It will return a base64 encoded string of the thumbnail image. Thumbnail size is 200x200.

Unfortunately the thumbnail endpoint is undocumented, at this point in time.

Comment: This is not a proper solution, that endpoint is to retrieve the asset thumbnail. It means that it returns the asset, not the final email sent, so if you use the same asset for different purposes, you won't see the final result.

In my humble opinion, this other question targets better the goal:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68478194/low-resolution-email-preview-in-salesforce-for-marketing-cloud-connect-emails

Comment: Sorry you didn't find my answer useful, however, I humbly disagree. Nowhere in the OP's question does it request for a preview of each individual email sent. Instead it seems they had some sort of external software to "create/edit the emails" and "set up marketing campaigns" and wanted a thumbnail of the saved email in SFMC so they could show that to users in their software interface.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there's an easy way. But, you can get the HTMLBody property of the Email, put that on a div in a webpage and then use a bit of code to generate a thumbnail that you can save out of that page. Libraries like: http://labs.awesomium.com/capturing-web-pages-with-c-net/ or http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/ might help out.

It will require a bit of custom work but could be done that way...

Comment: Yeah... the obvious and less desirable solution; Just seems like ET should've implemented this already with their SOAP api.. If it was a feature, and existed already, adding it to the API would've been simple, and I surely would've knowing that someone out there would use it. Then again, I am a perfectionist.