# Rendering Email Thumbnail in Hub

Tags: email, marketing-cloud, curl

Is it possible to make a cURL POST for an email thumbnail preview using the Authorization: Bearer header to a URL like this:

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/guide/v1/emails/12345/EmailThumbnail

Currently, this works sometimes, but I'm not sure how to always make it work.
https://members.exacttarget.com/Content/Email/EmailThumbnail.aspx?eid=12345&w=200&h=300

Answer (score 7):

The route listed in this question is unsupported. It should not be used in production environments. This route may stop working or become unavailable at any time with no notice.

Answer (score -2):

There isn't a lot of information in your post, but it would appear that your not the first to experience a problem in this area. See [Get Email Preview Thumbnail](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28803/get-email-preview-thumbnail)  and a prior post on Code@ [Retrieving a thumbnail image of an email via API?](https://code.exacttarget.com/question/retrieving-thumbnail-image-email-api)

It is possible to make a POST to our API using cURL with the Authorization header. An example GET request with cURL would look like this:

```
curl -H'Authorization: Bearer OAUTH_TOKEN' https://www.exacttargetapis.com/platform/v1/tokenContext
```

If it's only working some of the time I would guess that the problem is related to authorization. Make sure that you're generating a new token every time.

If you need instructions on getting a login token which will let you go directly to the email page see [Getting a Usertoken for Entity Direct Login](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/getting_a_usertoken_for_entity_direct_login/)

BTW. this a similar approach used by some of the ExactTarget productized CRM integrations as well so it's known to be working.